# Framework7 frustration

Tags: cordova, mobile, html-framework-7

I am beginner of F7. Everything goes well until the installation of F7 but when I run the command "Framework7 create" it says Framework7 is not recognized as internal command or operable.
anybody who can help?

Answer (score 0):

I have spent nearly 1 month solving these "not internal command or operable"
issues altogether.
Every time I face this problem It was a real trouble.
And the answers always got down to the environment variable PATH.
Whether it be cordova, node, python or npm command, the path to their executables should be included in PATH variable for them to be invoked.
Don't be afraid of this error ever.
Just add PATH.

Answer (score 0):

<"Something" is not recognized as internal command> is a standard message from Windows command line shell (called cmd.exe). It's a very simple and basic thing. If you do not know that I only can suggest to learn Windows basics like writing/programming using batch shell - i.e. .bat or which is the same .cmd files. That will definitely help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the Framework CLI along with Node.JS is installed on your computer. So first install [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and then open NPM command prompt and type `npm install -g framework7-cli`, this will install Framework7 CLI and then type `framework7 create` that probably should work.

Answer (score 0):

After setting up enviroment variable, I got this issue when running framework7 create, it only opens js file.[image]